# Disconnect vs Disable Networking?

Tags: networking

What does disconnecting from a connection do vs disabling networking?

Comment: I have added an answer. Remember to mark as answer if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling networking stops the network manager which is responsible for connecting to WiFi and using Ethernet while disconnecting just disconnects from the internet. You don't need to disable networking unless you have changed configuration or something.

So if you haven't changed any networking settings they should do the same thing